# Is there a way to modify session varaibles in mybatis?

Tags: mysql, session-variables, mybatis

For example, the MySQL `group_concat` function will truncate at 1024 characters, and I want to [change it to a bigger size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). Where can I set `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=2048` when using mybatis?

I know there is a way to achieve this by simply using the jdbc URL: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db>?sessionVariables=group_concat_max_len=2048`, so the jdbc connections will be initialized with the altered session variables value, but I'm wondering how to achieve this in mybatis.

When creating `SqlSessionFactory`, I notice that the factory can obtain a `Configuration` with property settings, so I create the factory with `sessionVariables` altered:

```java
private static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
    DataSource dataSource = getDataSource();

    TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
    Environment environment = new Environment("development", transactionFactory, dataSource);


    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("sessionVariables", "group_concat_max_len=2048");
    configuration.setVariables(properties);

    configuration.addMapper(SomeMapper.class);
    return new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
}
```

However, it doesn't work. The `group_concat` still truncates at 1024 rather than 2048. I dived into the mybatis source, it seems that the property is not used at all.

So does it mean that mybatis doesn't support session variables? Then why can I set variables by the factory `Configuration`?

Comment: The configuration variables and JDBC connection properties are not related. Variables can be used in MyBatis' configuration and mappers. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve, but it should be possible to define a mapper method with `@Update("SET group_concat_max_len = 2048")` and call it from your application if that's what you mean by "in MyBatis". The SELECT statement with `group_concat` must be executed in the same session/transaction, of course.